# How to apply my own function with r::apply()

Tags: r, function, apply

I have following dataframe

```
   GRATE GSHAPE
1  0.04    1.0
2  0.08    0.5
3  0.12    2.0
```

I want to compute a new column COL by following function

```
myfun = function (Rmax=150, precision=0.1, grate, gshape){
  s = seq(0,Rmax,precision)
  R = pgamma(s, rate=grate, shape=gshape)
  Rc = 1-R
  Rc2 = Rc^2
  Rc2ds = Rc2*precision
  intRc2ds = sum(Rc2ds, na.rm=TRUE)
  return(intRc2ds)
}
```

This is not working correctly:

```
mydf$COL = apply(mydf, 2, myfun, grate=mydf$GRATE, gshape=mydf$GSHAPE)
```

How should I do this?

Comment: I didn't see what your function does but you are actually using it with vectors. Then you need to use apply with 1 as margin, not 2, and, taking a row as a "vector" inside the call to apply, use the 1st and 2nd argument of this vector as grate and gshape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you wish to accomplish exactly? Making it run across columns doesn't make sense, because then you never have both a grate and gshape, but only one at a time.

If you want to make it run across rows (so that you get an answer for the combinations of grate and gshape presented in your rows), this code works:

```
mydf$COL = apply(mydf, 1, function(x) {myfun(grate=x[1], gshape=x[2])})
```

Comment: Ah, I see, I missed the index. My bad!

Comment: I want to calculate, for each row, the integral of the square of the gamma cumulative distribution, with rate and shape given in the first two columns. I guess this answer by @kneijenhuijs is correct, I am testing it. Thanks!

Comment: Not too simple in fact, I mean that is a function within a function, ... Would never have found that on my own. Thanks!

Comment: The function should accomplish that. It isn't a simple solution, the function inside accomplishes the indexing of the vectors (as apply does not play nice with vectors). The solution from @jogo actually puts the indexing inside of the myfun function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `apply()` (inspired by @kneijenhuijs )

```
myfun = function (grate.gshape, Rmax=150, precision=0.1) {
  grate <- grate.gshape[1]; gshape <- grate.gshape[2]
  s = seq(0, Rmax, precision)
  Rc2ds = (1-pgamma(s, rate=grate, shape=gshape))^2 *precision
  sum(Rc2ds, na.rm=TRUE) # intRc2ds
}
apply(mydf, 1, myfun)
```

you can set the other parameters per "..."-argument of `apply()`

First I had this solution with `mapply()`:

```
mydf <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='GRATE GSHAPE
1  0.04    1.0
2  0.08    0.5
3  0.12    2.0')

myfun = function (grate, gshape, Rmax=150, precision=0.1){
  s = seq(0,Rmax,precision)
  R = pgamma(s, rate=grate, shape=gshape)
  Rc = 1-R
  Rc2 = Rc^2
  Rc2ds = Rc2*precision
  intRc2ds = sum(Rc2ds, na.rm=TRUE)
  return(intRc2ds)
}

mapply(myfun, mydf$GRATE, mydf$GSHAPE)
```

But then it is hard to set the other parameters (Rmax= and precision=).
One other solution can be `Vectorize(myfun, ...)`. The resulting function can work with vectors.